# Mobile website fails to load on blackberry

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, blackberry

We have a mobile website solution that is built with the following technologies:

- Asp.net mvc 4 (running in .net 4)
- Jquery Mobile (v1.3.0)
- Jquery validation

Could it be possible that any of these technologies are incompatible with Blackberry's built in browser ?

The test was done on Blackberry Bold 9900 (OS 7).

Currently when opening the website we get an indication that the page is loading , some elements flicker and then it stops and only shows a blank page. After downloading Opera for blackberry the website displayed correctly. Could it be that blackberry browser is so outdated?

I know this is a very vauge question. Perhaps someone has expirienced this kind of behavior before with blackberry ? I'm just looking for ideas as to where to start looking.

Here is a code snippet of the document header, perhaps something here could be the cause ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Ommited</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="icon" href="/jecon.ico" sizes="16x16 32x32 72x72" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
        <meta name="description" content="Ommited"
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Ommited.css" />
    </head>
```

At the bottom of the layout page we have:

```js
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).live('pageinit', function () {
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
            });
        </script>
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

The validation was parsed above on `document.live` to fix the forms after ajax request (which jquery mobile does alot of)

Comment: Blackberry uses the Dolphin browser and all of this is compatible with that save for the Asp.net which is a server-side technology.

Comment: Yes I am aware that the serverside code does not have an effect on the phone, I was mentioning the use of mvc to give insight into the type of application design, and perhaps someone has come across this before while using a similar application design.

Comment: This is a very vague and generalized problem if you don't provide the snippet of code that is causing Blackberry's built in browser to hang.  If it works in Opera and not in Dolphin, then the default answer is you have a bug in your code.  It is presumptuous for you to automatically assume the bug is in the browser.  Always suspect your own code before blaming a browser.

Comment: I can't really post code snippets unless you want me to upload the whole website, because I don't really have any indication of where the problem might be. Could it be the doctype for html ? could it be a script incompatibility ? could it be some vendor specific thing with blackberry itself ?

Comment: Building the app with MVC wouldn't have an affect on this working on a Blackberry.

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile? Cant seem them in `<head>`. if yes, jQuery and jQuery-Mobile should be placed in `<head>` not somewhere else.

Comment: Yes using jquery mobile, but as the standard practice in mvc we have our script files at the bottom of the page. I will include a code snippet for that. Do you think this is a bad practice ?

Comment: Yea, It will affect jQuery Mobile performance. try moving them to `<head>` and test your page. Use CDN-hosted to test your page `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Placing the JS includes at the top of the page is probably a good idea because they are necessary to render the proceeding page.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with the default Blackberry browser in the past. I was also using jQuery Core 1.7.1 and by going back to 1.6.4 the issue was fixed. This was when 1.7.1 was the latest core available and 1.6.4 was the latest core supported by jQuery Mobile, so you may be able to upgrade rather than downgrade at this point.

The jQuery Mobile website suggests the usage of jQuery Core 1.9.1 with jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 (I'm not sure if it's the same for 1.3.0 but it seems likely).

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/04/10/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-3-1/*